# Creating a mutually exclusive or in prolog

Tags: prolog

Say you have a group of people who played chess. You want to determine if a player exists who never lost to anybody (undefeated). Suppose the facts are given as won(james, tom). won(james, peter), won(craig, tom). lost(peter, tom). Then a player X has never lost according to the conditions.

```
undefeated(X) :- \+ won(_, X), \+ lost(X, _).
```

so undefeated(james) is true and undefeated(craig) are true but undefeated(tom) and undefeated(peter) are false. Now the problem arises when calling undefeated(X) as this will simply return no. To resolve this we want a statement that is always true at the start so we add facts whiteplayer() and blackplayer() for a player who plays white and black pieces respectively.

```
whiteplayer(james).
whiteplayer(craig).
whiteplayer(tom).
whiteplayer(peter).
blackplayer(james).
blackplayer(peter).
blackplayer(tom).
```

and change undefeated to:

```
undefeated(X) :- (whiteplayer(X); blackplayer(X)), \+ won(_, X), \+ lost(X, _).
```

But now we run into a new problem. Querying undefeated(X) gives solutions james, craig, james, this happens since james plays both white and black pieces but craig only plays white pieces. So the problem is undefeated(james) is proceeding to continue for both whiteplayer(james) and blackplayer(james), how can I make it so that it only proceeds for one of these while backtracking?

Comment: Why do you have both `won/2` and `lost/2` facts in your database? They're redundant, which leads to some confusion. Isn't `won(X, Y)` equivalent to `lost(Y, X)`?

Comment: @lurker Yes they're equivalent, and I am unfortunately stuck dealing with both of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your facts and rules allow a specific instantiation of variables to succeed multiple ways, you're going to get duplicates unless you use a cut (which also then generally eliminates valid solutions, which is not desirable), or you can collect the redundant subsolutions using `setof` (or "manually") which eliminates duplicates.

So you can do something like this:

```
validplayer(X) :- whiteplayer(X) ; blackplayer(X).

undefeated(Player) :-
    setof(P, validplayer(P), Players),
    member(Player, Players),
    \+ won(_, Player), \+ lost(Player, _).
```

Ideally, it's better if you can define `validplayer/1` such that it succeeds once for any given player and doesn't cut. But your current definition of facts don't enable this.

I would also suggest you shouldn't need both `won/2` and `lost/2` facts, since `won(X, Y)` is equivalent to `lost(Y, X)`. It's best to stick with one or the other. Hopefully, your database doesn't have both `won(john, paul)` and `lost(paul, john)` or the above solution will still yield duplicates and you'd need to do the `setof/3` on `undefeated/1`: `setof(U, undefeated(U), ListOfUndefeatedPlayers)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that there is atleast one person who won from `X` then `X` is not undefeated. Simply you just try to find atleast one `Z` such that `Z` won from `X`.If this happends then it means that prolog finds a match and it will try to return true and you just invert that value in false and cut all other branches.

Same goes for one who is not undfeated. In this case prolog find no match and returns false without inverting it's value.

This is your code if i understood your questionr right btw it's always good to use guitracer to see what's going on.

```
won(james,tom). 
won(james,peter).
won(craig,tom). 
lost(peter,tom).



undefeated(X):-
  \+ won(_Z,X),!.
```

Comment: `undefeated(X)` query just results in no solutions.

Comment: should not he call undefeated with a term as paramter or is he trying to find all people who are not undefeated!

Comment: This is going to fail if you add the fact lost(james, tom). and it also won't return all the solutions for undefeated(X)

Comment: @Greg Thanks for comment, i'm always hungry to learn something new but I never said it returns all solutions btw why do you need lost predicate because if someone is undefeated --> he never lost!

Comment: @LuaiGhunim If you add the fact lost(james, tom). then james has lost to tom in a game, therefore he is no longer undefeated. You must check both won and lost facts

Comment: @Greg yes it does btw are you trying to get all names who are undefeated or simply yes or no?

Comment: If you read Greg's question carefully, he's looking for it to return all solutions. If a predicate fails for a valid solution, or doesn't provide all of the available solutions, then it is flawed.

Comment: the OP says they must deal with both `won/2` and `lost/2`. (and how much better is `lost/2`, compared with [`lost/6`](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/lost-season-7-new-series-is-inevitable-says-showrunner-9764252.html)!!.....;):)